# Session-id w/Serilog in Blazor ServerSide?

Tags: blazor-server-side, serilog

In aspnet, I can set a "session" log pr request using

```
 using (LogContext.PushProperty("CorrelationId", "SomeUniqeSessionId"));
```

and then use the Disposal pattern to pop the property off again, so I have a id to track the users session.

In Blazor Serverside, how can I get the same functionality ? I want to have the log message from the same user session correlated, in order to track "ok, what did the user do to get to here and cause this error?"

A F5 refresh on the browser should then give a new session ID (afaicu), since its re-loading the entire page. Off course I can subclass the logger, or store it in a custom session object, but would like to use the "normal" Serilog constructs, where the logger is injected ect ect.